# VB.NET database access efficiency for bulk processing

Tags: database, vb.net, multithreading, oracle

I have a VB.NET application that is processing a large volume of data from an Oracle database and performing calculations on the data retrieved.  The data is being retrieved from 3 related tables.

The main table has a single record for each item that needs to be calculated (slightly less than 1 million rows at this time). There is a one-to-many relationship to each of the other two tables with an average of 20 records in the subsidiary tables to each record in the main table (about 20 million rows total).

I am currently retrieving the data using an OracleDataReader object to access a stored procedure that returns a REF_CURSOR to the result of a query that joins these tables.  The .NET code reads the records one at a time and uses the primary key column to group a set of records from this result set into a computation batch which it then performs the required calculations on.

The processing time for this application is longer than I currently want and I am looking  for a more efficient way to access this data for processing that could support multithreading of the application so multiple worker threads could perform the calculations on each set of main record / sub-record sets from my database. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think multi-threading is going to buy you all that much. Have you examined the Explain Plan to see if the query is performing optimally? If the calculations are (and can be) performed on the DB server, would that reduce the result set size and overall performance?

Comment: Haven't looked at the explain plan, but the query performance does not really seem to be an issue. When executing the query by itself, it returns a complete result set in acceptable time.  Bottleneck seems to be in my processing of the records returned where I have to read primary key column from each row returned to know where the set of records associated with each main table record ends before I can continue my calculations.  Calculations cannot be performed on DB server unfortunately.

Comment: Does the processing need to happen in VB?  If you process the data in SQL, you can let Oracle take care of parallelizing it (assuming that is necessary and useful) and you don't have to pull all the data across the network.

Comment: Yes, the processing needs to be in application side code.  The computations being performed are fairly complex and have variations based on user inputs in a GUI that is part of the application.

Comment: How are the calculations being performed? LINQ? An example may be helpful.

Comment: All the calculations are just regular VB code. The reason for putting it in the VB code was due to the excessive number of optional calculations and methods for performing calculations that the user wanted.  At start up, the application attaches event handlers specific to the options the user selected from the GUI.  When we pull back a block of records from the database, it raises an event and lets the calculations just flow from there.  I guess in theory I could build custom SQL to pass to the database instead and let it process DB side.